# Looping through URLs in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to extract multiple bits of data from over 500 URLs which are all structured the same: www.domain.com/something-else_uniqueID

The code I've tried is:

```
url <- c("www.domain.com/something-else_uniqueID",
         "www.domain.com/something-else_uniqueID2",
         "www.domain.com/something-else_uniqueID3")

lapply(url, function(x) {

data.frame(url=url, 
         category=category <- read_html(url) %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="content-anchor"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/a') %>%
           html_text(),

         sub_category=sub_category <- read_html(url) %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="content-anchor"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]/a') %>%
           html_text(),

         section=section <- read_html(url) %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="content-anchor"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[4]/a') %>%
           html_text())

}) -> my_effort

write.csv(my_effort, "mydata.csv")
```

1. RStudio returns in red: Error: expecting a single value
2. Because there are so many URLs, is there a more efficient way than c()?

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use `url` in your function while you would rather use `x` that is the current item being iterated

Try with

```
url <- c("www.domain.com/something-else_uniqueID",
         "www.domain.com/something-else_uniqueID2",
         "www.domain.com/something-else_uniqueID3")

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), 
    lapply(url, function(x) {
       data.frame(url=x, 
           category=category <- read_html(x) %>%
                   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="content-anchor"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/a') %>%
                   html_text(),

           sub_category=sub_category <- read_html(x) %>%
                   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="content-anchor"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]/a') %>%
                   html_text(),

           section=section <- read_html(x) %>%
                   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="content-anchor"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[4]/a') %>%
                   html_text())

    })) -> my_effort

write.csv(my_effort, "mydata.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you - that works a treat. Trouble now is, the data frame fills up sideways, repeating the title again and again (category, category2 etc) so how to get it into one column for each?

Comment: Try this `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), (result_of_lapply))`

Comment: HubertL, that looks amazing but I'm afraid it's beyond my paygrade. I entered rbind.data.frame at the beginning of the function and it worked to a degree. It returned all the URLs as columns so I transposed them in Excel.